# I have installed Berkeley DB 5.1.25.msi Windows installer

Tags: java, berkeley-db

I have installed Berkeley DB 5.1.25.msi Windows installer and now I want to connect to it with a Java API.  How can I do that?

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: i mean i want to connect berkeleydb with java programme so i m not getting jdbc driver for that ? so how to connect berkeleydb with java

Answer (score 1):

The [Berkeley DB](http://www.oracle.com/us/products/database/berkeley-db/db/index.html) web page at Oracle says there's a JDBC driver.  You'd probably use that to access the database from Java.

Alternatively, the [Berkeley DB Java Edition](http://www.oracle.com/us/products/database/berkeley-db/je/index.html) is a pure Java version of Berkeley DB.  You might find that easier to embed in a Java application.